# not receiving right double value

Tags: java, mysql

```
public double getPrice(String name) throws SQLException {
    TechnoRepository repo = TechnoRepository.getInstance();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select price from products where name = '?';");
    if(rs.next())
       return rs.getDouble("price");   
    return 0;
}
```

Main class :

```
TechnoRepository repo = TechnoRepository.getInstance();
double price = repo.getPrice("water");
System.out.printf("%.2f",price);
```

Result is 0.0, not the right one

Comment: Original code would not have compiled (`price` was not declared).  Side note: `double`s can't store certain amounts, like `.1`, -exactly-, which can make accountants nervous.  You should be storing anything money-related in a `BigDecimal` (Java), and `decimal`/`numeric` (SQL).

Answer (score 3):

You look to be trying to do a `PreparedStatement`, hence the question mark in the sql code.

However, since you are only creating a `Statement` you make your search in the table `products` where the name is equal to the literal `?`. And since your table, presumably, does not contain a such character, there is no data in the `ResultSet`.

```
    public double getPrice(String name) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select price from products where name = ?;";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        prepStmt.setString(1, name);

        ResultSet resultSet = prepStmt.executeQuery();

        double price = 0.0;
        if(rs.next())
            price = rs.getDouble("price");

        return price;
}
```

where `prepStmt.setString(1, name);` is where you replace with the first encountered `?` with, in this case, the `name`.

Comment: **THANK** you for knowing the proper way to do this.